# NServiceBus: How to get max first level retries from IBus

Tags: c#, nservicebus

In our App.config we have configured the maximum first level retries property as follows:

```
<TransportConfig MaxRetries="3" />
```

I was wondering how to retrieve this value from an IBus. Essentially the method would look like this:

```
public int GetMaximumFirstLevelRetries(IBus bus)
{
    // How to read the setting?
}
```

I want to avoid reading the setting from the App.config or Web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it:

```
public int GetMaximumFirstLevelRetries(IBus bus)
{
    var unicastBus = (UnicastBus)bus;
    var transportConfig = unicastBus.Settings.GetConfigSection<TransportConfig>();
    return transportConfig.MaxRetries;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could instantiate `TransportConfig` and read the value in the following way:

```
var transportConfig = new ServiceBus.Config.TransportConfig();
transportConfig.MaxRetries
```

Comment: More clearly, the result is always 5 which is the default. But I want to retrieve the configured setting without reading the App.config directly.